# Magento2 - Removing inline translations does not revert to original string

Tags: localisation, inline-translations

I have a web site that was originally translated using inline translation. I am in the process of moving the translations to a .csv file. However when i remove the translations from the inline translation fields, instead of reverting back to the default string it becomes empty (showing nothing) and the editing field becomes broken.

**Screenshot of the Inline Translation fields**

[image]

**Screenshot of Inline Translation form**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go to the template and delete `__()` and leave the string inside.

For example:

Original string:

```
echo __('Filter by %1', $filter->getName());
```

String without translate in csv:

```
echo 'Filter by', $filter->getName();
```

By deleting `__()` Magento doesn't search this string in the translation csv.